# Diagonal union in ZFC: a picture

Tags: elementary-set-theory, reference-request, intuition, boolean-algebra, reference-works

Is it possible to **draw**-create a picture even by hand, the **diagonal union** concept in set theory ?
It is denoted by $\triangledown\cal A$ and defined to be $\{z ∈ Z :
\text{for some }x ∈ z, z ∈ A_x\}$ where ${\cal A
} = 〈A_x : x ∈ X〉$ is a sequence of subsets of $Z ⊆{\cal P }(X)$

There are various equivalent definitions of this, but none of which is intuitive enough.

Comment: $\mathcal A$ is really a function: $X\to\mathcal P(\mathcal P(X)),$ and I don't really see a good way to to envision that. What kind of picture are you looking for?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Any **pencil picture art** could be possible. Just to *visualize* what is going on here in a 2 dimensional array, say, will do. And get rid off higher dimensionality in the text from my OQ.

Comment: If you let $\mathcal B_x=\{z\subseteq X\mid x\in z\}$ then it is:

$$\bigcup_x \left(\mathcal A_x\cap \mathcal B_x\right)$$  But I don't see a way to visually represent this. The $Z$ is redundant - you can always start with $\mathcal A_x\subseteq \mathcal P(X)$ and define $Z=\bigcup A_x.$

Comment: And the word "sequence of subsets" here is a misnomer. It is better to use "index set/family of subsets..."

Answer (score 2):

The definition you give in your question is for taking the diagonal union of *a family of sets, the elements of each of which are subsets of some fixed set $X$*. A different definition that I think is more conducive being represented  visually is for taking the diagonal union of *a family of sets of ordinals, each of which is a subset of some fixed cardinal $\kappa$*. On the surface, this other definition seems less general, but, since the Axiom of Choice implies that any set can be well-ordered, any diagonal union under your definition is can be regarded as one under this other definition.

For reference, here are the definitions found in Jech's *Set Theory: The Third Millenium Edition* (with notation changed to match that in your question):

Let $\langle X_\alpha : \alpha < \kappa \rangle$ be a sequence of subsets of $\kappa$. The *diagonal intersection* of $X_\alpha$ is

$$\underset{\alpha < \kappa}{\triangle} X_\alpha = \{ \xi < \kappa : \xi \in \bigcap_{\alpha < \xi} X_\alpha\}$$

and the *diagonal union* of $X_\alpha$ is

$$\underset{\alpha < \kappa}{\bigtriangledown} X_\alpha = \{ \xi < \kappa : \xi \in \bigcup_{\alpha < \xi} X_\alpha\}.$$

Each $X_\alpha$ is a subset of $\kappa$, so we can represent it visually as a tower of $\kappa$ many dots, with dots filled in for elements of $\kappa$ that are in $X_\alpha$, and dots left open for elements of $\kappa$ that are not in $X_\alpha$. For example, a typical $X_\alpha$ might look like this:

[image]

The entire sequence $\langle X_\alpha : \alpha < \kappa \rangle$ might look like this:

[image]

The "diagonal" that is relevant in the diagonal intersection and union is the following one:

[image]

For a given $\xi < \kappa$, we have $\xi \in \underset{\alpha < \kappa}{\triangle} X_\alpha$ if and only if *every* dot in the $\xi$th row to the left of the red line is filled in, and $\xi \in \underset{\alpha < \kappa}{\bigtriangledown} X_\alpha$ if and only if *at least one* dot in the $\xi$th row to the left of the red line is filled in. For example, in the picture I drew, we have $3 \in \underset{\alpha < \kappa}{\triangle} X_\alpha$ and $2 \in \underset{\alpha < \kappa}{\bigtriangledown} X_\alpha$.